# How to write most efficient code for the following matching problem?

Tags: math, matching, tax

Need to match tax records from two Tables (A and B) each having a record with 10 type of values and classify them in 4 different buckets as follow:

1. Match
2. Mismatch (show where exactly is a mismatch and identify approximate mismatches as well for instance INV-200 and INV/200)
3. Not in Table A
4. Not in Table B

While the code has been written, first in PHP (For each loop) and then in Python (using Pandas, joints).

The performance is bad. Millions of records can't be processed.

How to do it?

Comment: What have you done so far, what exactly do you want to do? It seems like you are outsourcing your work.

Comment: How are your records stored? If they are stored in files on a hard drive, disk access could be your liimiting factor. Otherwise, show the code you have tried to use so we can see where you are coming from.

Comment: Unless you have an index available, you'll have to do a table scan over millions of records.  Mismatch suggests that indexes cannot be used here.